# Centre an image next to paragraphs using TailwindCSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, tailwind-css

I am trying to vertically align an image next to a paragraph using TailwindCSS. Take a look at the following Codepen which demonstrates the problem I'm facing:

```
https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/rNWPWxr
```

```
<div class="bg-red-500">
  <div class="w-full m-auto mt-8 px-8 py-6 items-center mb-6">
    <img class="float-right align-middle sm:block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tamas-demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto,q_auto,z_0.7/woman.jpg" />
    <p class="text-white leading-normal font-bold text-2xl lg:text-3xl mb-8" id="greeting">Hi hi hi</p>
    <p class="text-white leading-normal justify-between font-normal md:text-xl lg:text-2xl sm:w-3/4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc odio ante, placerat eget mollis vitae, vehicula congue magna. Fusce euismod ac tortor quis varius. Nullam quis arcu mauris. Nunc sit amet elit non dolor varius luctus. Fusce eget odio imperdiet ex cursus hendrerit. Aenean quis enim eu ante blandit venenatis. Nullam quis sollicitudin neque. Aenean hendrerit fringilla risus, pellentesque elementum neque.

      Cras pretium a arcu quis cursus. Donec eu nisl scelerisque, venenatis neque a, consectetur magna. Suspendisse vestibulum neque vel metus feugiat maximus. Aliquam eu ligula vitae dui consectetur venenatis. Sed iaculis convallis nisi. Etiam placerat varius sem, non placerat neque consectetur et. Duis id risus lacinia ligula euismod aliquet et quis nibh. Sed odio mi, consectetur ac eros id, blandit interdum libero. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum bibendum sapien sed commodo pharetra. Fusce venenatis eget arcu et eleifend. Aliquam erat volutpat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to vertically align the image on the right side.

Comment: Do you mean you want to align the top of the image with the top of the "Lorem ipsum" paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<div class="bg-red-500">
  <div class="w-full m-auto mt-8 px-8 py-6 items-center mb-6" style = "display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;">
    <img class=" align-middle sm:block" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tamas-demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto,q_auto,z_0.7/woman.jpg"/>
    <div>
    <p class="text-white leading-normal font-bold text-2xl lg:text-3xl mb-8" id="greeting">Hi hi hi</p>
    <p class="text-white leading-normal justify-between font-normal md:text-xl lg:text-2xl sm:w-3/4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc odio ante, placerat eget mollis vitae, vehicula congue magna. Fusce euismod ac tortor quis varius. Nullam quis arcu mauris. Nunc sit amet elit non dolor varius luctus. Fusce eget odio imperdiet ex cursus hendrerit. Aenean quis enim eu ante blandit venenatis. Nullam quis sollicitudin neque. Aenean hendrerit fringilla risus, pellentesque elementum neque.

      Cras pretium a arcu quis cursus. Donec eu nisl scelerisque, venenatis neque a, consectetur magna. Suspendisse vestibulum neque vel metus feugiat maximus. Aliquam eu ligula vitae dui consectetur venenatis. Sed iaculis convallis nisi. Etiam placerat varius sem, non placerat neque consectetur et. Duis id risus lacinia ligula euismod aliquet et quis nibh. Sed odio mi, consectetur ac eros id, blandit interdum libero. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum bibendum sapien sed commodo pharetra. Fusce venenatis eget arcu et eleifend. Aliquam erat volutpat.
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```